# Any ideas on a workaround for a formula custom field that needs to be edited by system administrator?

Tags: formula-field, read-only

I want to create a custom field on the opportunity level 'Sale Made By'. This should be automatically generated as the user (salesperson) that converted the lead to account.

However, what adds complexity is that I need to be able to edit this field (change who made the sale) in certain cases as system administrator. I understand that it is not possible to edit a formula field given that it is read-only, however I was wondering if there was an easy work around?

At the moment, the field is generated by a simple formula 'CreatedBy.Username', but obviously this means the field cannot be generated.

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The way my org handles this is to have a second 'override' field that is only editable by our target profiles.

Your formula field would then need to change to be something like this

```
IF(
    NOT(ISBLANK(Sale_Made_By_Override__c)),
    Sale_Made_By_Override__c,
    CreatedBy.Username
)
```

Not the most elegant solution, but it works for us.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the easiest way would be use WFR or process builder to initially populate the field (Basic Text Field) if null (on creation).

Then you can simply use Field Level Security to make the field viewable by all the users and editable by some. If you want to add a validation rule around when the field can be edited you could add that additional level for those that can edit it.